# How do I close jQuery Accordion effect on second click?

Tags: jquery, accordion

I've recently bought 'Smashing jQuery' by Jake Rutter - it's a  good book, but I'm stuck modifying a bit of 'Accordion' code.

When a section is clicked it expands as intended, but if clicked a second time (while still open) it closes only to instantly open again.

I want the expanded section to close if it's clicked a second time, only opening again if it's clicked. Hope this makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

Please see the demo URL below for an example and code I've used.
http://demos.d3-creative.com/accordion/accordion-1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need something like below to make it work. See the comments:

```
var $header = $('.accordion-header'),//always cache your selectors
    $content = $('.accordion-content');

$header.click(function () {

    var $this = $(this),
        $relatedContent = $this.next();

    if($relatedContent.is(':visible')) { // If the tab is already open

        $relatedContent.slideUp('fast');

        $this.find('.icon-active').removeClass('icon-active');

        $this.removeClass('header-active');

    } else { // if the tab is closed

        // Close any other opened tabs
        $content.slideUp('fast');
        $header.removeClass('header-active');
        $header.find('span').removeClass('icon-active');

       // Open related tab
        $relatedContent.slideDown('fast');

        $this.find('span').addClass('icon-active');

        $this.addClass('header-active');
    }

});
```

And add `display:none` to `#accordion .accordion-content`

Comment: Can you at least tell what error it is throwing in the console or what part is not working? My sample code was only to give you an idea.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the syntax error after I checked Ben's jsFiddle.

Comment: Works! Thanks Sandeep and Ben Baudart, I've uploaded a complete working example here:

http://demos.d3-creative.com/accordion/accordion-2/accordion-2.html

Really appreciate your help on this! Been scratching my head all day on this one.

Answer (score 0):

have a read:

http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

you need to add some if / else logic to the click function otherwise each time you click on a section it is going to execute all the code in the function.

Comment: Won't circumventing the widget logic this mess up its internal state somehow?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I could really do with some more help on this. I want it to work like the link below. I've tried editing the code (in the link) but I can't get it to do what I want (that's why I bought the book). http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#collapsible

Comment: set your code up on jsfiddle and then we can have a look as the examples / answers already provided should be working

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this in the JS part:

```
$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
    $('.accordion-header').next().slideUp('fast'); // Close all boxes - Hide all contents
    $('.accordion-header').removeClass('header-active'); // Remove active class from all headers
    $(this).addClass('header-active'); // Adds active class to currently clicked element
    $(this).next().slideDown('fast'); // Shows content

    $('.icon-active:visible').removeClass('icon-active');
    $(this).find('span').addClass('icon-active');

});
```

I have changed the behaviour so that whenever you click on a header, it first closes all content boxes, then removes the active class on all headers, then it slides open the box directly following the clicked element and also changes its class. Code is commented as you can see!

Exemple here: http://jsfiddle.net/snzSy/

Also, I didn't modify the last 2 lines, regarding the icons!

**Side note:** We are both beginners here, so I can freely tell you that it's easier for people to help you if you take some time to prepare your question. A JS fiddle is good, because we can then directly test and modify your code....

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this for me. I'll use JS fiddle in future. I dropped the code into my file, and checked the JS fiddle page you kindly setup and neither produced the required effect? Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks Ben. I fixed a syntax error that was stopping the answer I provided from working :)

Comment: Thanks again Ben, Sandeep's solution worked (after looking at yours). Huge thanks to both of you for your time and effort in solving this. I'll be sure to use JS Fiddle from now on! :)